# AttributeError: 'Persona' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, django-forms

Buen día comunidad. Tengo un problema al momento de guardar los datos de un formulario de tipo ModelForm. Y es que cuando envió los datos del formulario a mi base de datos aparece el siguiente error:

```
AttributeError at /Usuario/
'Persona' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Enseguida adjunto el código de mi formulario, vista y template.

Formulario:

```
class PersonaForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Persona
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, nombre, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PersonaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['nombre'].initial = nombre
```

Vista:

```
def index(request):

    nombre = Persona.objects.get(pk = 5)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonaForm(request.POST or None,nombre)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('Usuario:index')
    else:
        form = PersonaForm(nombre)

    context = {
        'form':form,    
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Modelos:

```
class Nacion(models.Model):
     pais = models.CharField('Nombre pais', max_length=50)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.pais

class Persona(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField('Nombre', max_length=50)
    apellido = models.CharField('Apellido', max_length=50)
    edad = models.IntegerField('Edad')
    nacionalidad = models.ForeignKey(Nacion, verbose_name=("Nacion"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Template:

```
<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Básicamente estoy teniendo problemas al guardar mi formulario, creo por que hay algo en mi función `__init__` que no estoy haciendo bien, lo que quiero con este código es generar argumentos en el formulario y esos pasarlos en la vista.

Agrego la imagen del error que sale en el navegador, es la linea 14 de la vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En qué línea te arroja el error. Quizás es más fácil ayudarte conociendo el trace del error.

Comment: Listo, agregue el error, es en la linea 14 de la vista.

Comment: Hola. ¿Puedes mostrar tus modelos?

Comment: Listo Cesar, agregue los modelos